# Como criar vários menus na mesma página com xhtml

Tags: css, xhtml

Não estou a conseguir colocar na mesma página, por exemplo dois menus.

Passo a explicar. Uso as listas não ordenadas e o display inline para criar um menu horizontal.

Faço o mesmo para mais abaixo da página criar outro.

O que penso que está a falhar é individualizar ambos. Para isso estou a usar o ID no `ul` e no `li` dos dois menus. No menu 1 estou a usar um ID diferente para o `ul` e outro para as `li` (no caso das listas uso o mesmo nome de ID para todas). E faço o mesmo para o segundo menu claro que os ID´s são diferentes do primeiro menu.

Bem, o objetivo é ter a capacidade de usar formatações independentes. Não estou a conseguir.

Já andei a passar os olhos em muitos sites e livros e não encontro nada. Alguém pode ajudar-me? Estou a dar os primeiros passos na prática. Obrigado.

Em baixo têm um exemplo. Não coloquei tudo certo como por exemplo o  etc só está o que interessa para o exercicio

```
<ul class="menu1">
    <li><a href="#">EXEMPLO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">EXEMPLO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">EXEMPLO</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu2">
    <li><a href="#">EXEMPLO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">EXEMPLO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">EXEMPLO</a></li>
</ul>
```

Depois nas css está assim:

```
.menu1 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 50px;
} 

li {    
    font-family: globerthin, Verdana, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif;
    display: inline;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;    
    font-family: globerthin, Verdana, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif;    
}

.menu1 a:link{
    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

a:visited {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
    background-color: #faf6eb;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: #faf6eb;
}
```

No menu dois está assim:

```
.menu2 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 30px;
} 

li {    
    font-family: globerthin, Verdana, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif;
    display: inline;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;    
    font-family: globerthin, Verdana, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif;    
}

#menu a:link{
    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

a:visited {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
    background-color: #faf6eb;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: #faf6eb;
}
```

Comment: Seria possível disponibilizar o código para darmos uma olhada? Você mencionou que está utilizando para os **li** o mesmo **ID**, acredito não ser a melhor abordagem, um ID não deve se repetir dentro do mesmo código HTML, ele deve ser único, para os **li** sugiro você utilizar o elemento class pois esse sim pode se repetir e serve como formatados visual.

Comment: Olá fábio. Eu sei que a class se usa quando queremos repetir as css e o ID é o elemento único. Apesar de os dois terem o mesmo efeito na prática. No entanto, na teoria se trabalhar-mos com várias pessoas em páginas css externas eles saberam o que é unico na página de html. O problema não é ai... talvez seja na repetição dos atributos "li". Ainda estou a dar uma estudada a ver se encontro o erro. O problema não é a opção se uso ID ou class.

Comment: O problema é saber como faço dois menus horizontais com propriedades diferentes. Se você tentar fazer dois menus horizontais verá que quando tenta posiciona-los eles se orientam de igual forma. Penso que o problema pode está relacionado aos elementos "a" e por ai... obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: O que é que já tens até agora? [Edita](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/93050/edit) a tua pergunta e adiciona-lhe o código XHTML e CSS daquilo que já tens até agora.

Comment: Coloca o código html e css no seu post.

Comment: Penso já ter descoberto ou parcialmente descoberto. Primeiro de salientar que a propriedade "a" também tem o seu papel no css. Depois estou a reparar que ao invés de especificar o código colocando o "li mais a cass ou o id" devemos apenas colocar o id ou a class. Ainda não sei o motivo nem entendo bem como trabalha as listas para fazer menus e mais listas com vários estilos na mesma página. Penso que estou a caminhar no caminho certo.